# prove that a graph is one-ended

Tags: graph-theory, geometric-group-theory, finitely-generated

[image: Question + my solution]

I am not sure how to show the second part. Isn’t it obvious from the fact that    G and H are infinite?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You may want to look at [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to type math symbols in your posts.

Comment: Hi thanks, I will look at the link next time I'll post a question

Comment: You write "...$G \times H$ is also infinite group. Therefore, $G \times H$ contain $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup of infinite index", but this implication is not justified. Some infinite groups contain $\mathbb{Z}$ with finite index (such as $\mathbb{Z}$ itself); and some infinite groups contain no $\mathbb{Z}$ at all (the "Tarski monster groups").

Comment: You also write: "I am not sure how to show the second part. Isn't it obvious from the fact that $G$ and $H$ are infinite?" It is not obvious, because there does exist an infinite group that splits as an amalgamated product over a finite group. For example, each of the groups $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite and splits over the trivial group.

Comment: So, you have to use something special about the product of two infinite groups in order to conclude that this product does not split over a finite group.

Comment: One last thing: your statement of the Stallings Ends Theorem is incorrect. Item 3 should say that if $e(G)>2$ then $G$ splits **either** as either an amalgamated free product over a finite group **or** as an HNN amalgamation over a finite group.

Comment: Title says *graph*, body only concerns *groups*. Huh?

Answer (score 1):

The following was a bit too long for a comment so I wrote it as an answer:

In my opinion it is better to look at this problem in a pure structure theoretical fashion, since your assertion is true for any pair of connected infinite locally finite graphs. So nothing special about the graphs being Cayley graphs of some groups.

Hence: Let $X$ and $Y$ be two connected infinite locally finite graphs. Then their product $X \times Y$ has exactly one end.

There are lots of "different products" one could form with two given graphs. In this case we have $V(X \times Y) = V(X) \times V(Y)$ and the adjacency is defined as follows:

$(x_1, y_1)$ is adjacent to $(x_2, y_2)$ iff $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1$ is adjacent to $y_2$ or vice versa.

Let now $B$ be some ball of finite radius in $X \times Y$ and let $z,w$ be two vertices outside of $B$ and each inside some *infinite* component. If you find a path connecting them outside of $B$ you are done.

First think about the example $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and some ball in its Cayley graph (w.r.t some generating set). Why can you connect any two vertices outside this ball without touching the ball (consider the definition of the adjacency in such product graphs at the same time)?

I am confident that you can write it down in general.